# googleapis oauth2.0 + passport for user registration - nodejs express application

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am using `googleapis` oauth2.0 for user registration on my website through through `OAuth2.0`. I get to the point where I get the access token and id token and save the new user in my database, from that point on I want to create a user session and I am trying to use `passport` for it but `passport` needs one of its strategies to implement which I do not need at this point because I already have verified user email and everything and have saved the user in my database all I now need to do is create a user session and send the user to the home page but there seems to be no way to just create user session without a strategy in `passport`.

here is my oauth2.0 redirect function where I get the access token etc.

```
router.get('/oauth-redirect', function (req, res, next) = > {
    const data = await googleAuth.getToken(req.code);
    const user = getUserInfoFrom(data);
    const savedUser = save(user);
    //here: use passport to create a session and send the user to home page ????
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the way to do it, there is req.login() function exposed by passport that you can use to manually log the user in.

```
router.get('/oauth-redirect', function (req, res, next) = > {
    const data = await googleAuth.getToken(req.code);
    const user = getUserInfoFrom(data);
    const savedUser = save(user);
    //this below is what will create a session and will set connect.sid cookie
    req.login(savedUser, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        return res.redirect('/home');
    });
    
})
```